# Two routers on same subnet

Tags: subnet

This is my current setup:

```
Modem > Openwrt(wrt1200ac) > Pfsense
```

Openwrt creates a `192.168.2.1` subnet, and `pfsense` is assigned `192.168.2.100` on its wan interface.

Pfsense then creates a `192.168.1.1` subnet and all the computers plug here.

The setup was made because during power outages you can still connect to the openwrt router. It uses a lot less power than pfsense, so only the openwrt router is connected to the UPS.

This results in computers connected to the Openwrt router via wireless unable to connect to pfsense, which makes sense. Pfsense will see those computers on WAN and block them.

I tried to plug pfsense and openwrt into the same switch along with the computers. I unchecked authorize DHCP on openwrt's LAN. Computers are still assigned `192.168.1.x` ips so that's good.

So I tried to manually set a computer to `192.168.2.105` and it can ping to the internet sometimes but constantly drops packets. It also cannot connect to the `192.168.1.x` computers on pfsense either.

Is there a solution to make it so the computers on the different subnets can talk to each other?

I heard changing to /16 subnet mask might work, but I'm unsure of as to why.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but a comment on approach - I would remove the second router from the configuration. You're only increasing your failure probability by creating a linear chain like that, not considering the increased complexity.

Comment: I would but I wanted to use some of the features of pfsense. I'm also just curious on how you would even do this.

Comment: "_I wanted to use some of the features of pfsense_" Then use the pfSense router, and not the OpenWRT router. If you need wireless, then add a WAP on the network created by the pfSense router. Use the correct tools for the job.

Comment: @user340910 Did you already manage to get the network working with the pfsense router plugged directly into the modem and the wrt1200ac switched off? If that works for you then all that's left is to configure the wrt1200ac to act as access point.